# Is an element of a vector a scalar or 1x1 vector or 1x1 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, vector-spaces, vectors, economics

In econometrics, by Hayashi, they defined the error vector of n observations in a $ (n \times K)$ regression funcntion as:

$\epsilon = \begin{bmatrix}\epsilon_{1} \\\epsilon_{2} \\\vdots \\\epsilon_{n}\end{bmatrix}$, where $\epsilon_{i}$ is the ith observation's error term,

and K-dimension x vector of the ith observation as,  $x_{i} = \begin{bmatrix}x_{i1} \\x_{i2} \\\vdots \\x_{ik}\end{bmatrix}$

The book says that the **cross moment** of two random variables E[xy] is zero means that these two random variables are orthogonal. It's not hard to see the point using [0,1] and [1,0] to check their cross product for orthogonality.

But in the book it has a formula for strict exogeneity assumption:

$E[x_{j}\epsilon_{i}] = \begin{bmatrix}x_{j1}\epsilon_{i} \\x_{j2}\epsilon_{i} \\\vdots \\x_{jk}\epsilon_{i}\end{bmatrix} = 0_{(K\times1)}$

So, here the $\epsilon_{i}$ is an element of the $\epsilon$ vector, and the cross moment for a $(k\times1)$ vector and an element of a vector, which are orthogonal, is a $(k\times1)$ 0 vector. My question is that, what is a cross moment of two random variables, is it the expected value of the inner product? And shall I view the $\epsilon_{i}$ as a scalar, or $(1\times1)$ vector, or $(1\times1)$ matrix?

[image]
[image]
[image]
Thank you very much.

Comment: $1\times 1$ vector and $1\times 1$ matrix are the same thing; the main difference is what you think about them or what you do with them, not what they are. Similarly, the $1\times 1$ matrix/vectors behave exactly the same as scalars (check what happens when you add them or when you multiply them by suitably sized matrices/vectors). So it’s just a matter of whether you want to think of them as scalars or as vectors or as matrices, depending on context.

Comment: Can you quote your book's definition of the cross moment exactly? Specifically, is it defined when $X$ and $Y$ are random variables? Or when one is a random variable and one is a random matrix? Or when both are vectors?

Comment: Hi Mike, I just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors are (in this context) just matrices which have one row or column.

$\def\e{\epsilon}\e_i$ is a scalar, as it is an entry of a  matrix, $\e$.

The cross moment of two random variables $X,Y$ is defined as the expected value of their *product*, where the product being used depends on context.

- If $X$ and $Y$ are scalars, the product is usual multiplication.
- If $X$ is a scalar and $Y$ is a matrix, the product is scalar multiplication.
- If $X$ is and $Y$ are both matrices, then the product is matrix multiplication.

  - If $X$ is an $1\times n$ vector and $Y$ is an $n\times 1$ vector, then the product is a $1\times 1$ matrix, which can be thought of as a scalar with no loss of generality. If so, this scalar **is** their inner product.

In answer to your second question, there is one special case where the cross moment is the expected value of the inner product.

Comment: Hi Mike, I really appreciate your rigorous explanation, it helps me lot! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the n X 1 error vector is a random vector. A random vector of dimension n is a collection of n random variables that are associated to the same event. So in the error vector:
$$\epsilon = \begin{bmatrix}\epsilon_{1} \\\epsilon_{2} \\\vdots \\\epsilon_{n}\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\epsilon_i$ is the error in the $i^{th}$ observation, since the error is random every variable is random. 
Now the cross moment expression should be written like :
$$E[x_{j}\epsilon_{i}] = \begin{bmatrix}x_{j1}\epsilon_{i} \\x_{j2}\epsilon_{i} \\\vdots \\x_{jk}\epsilon_{i}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\0 \\\vdots \\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Now the error $\epsilon_1$ is actually the error observed in the vector $x_1=\begin{bmatrix}x_{11} \\x_{12} \\\vdots \\x_{1k}\end{bmatrix}$ which is again a vector so you are just checking the exogeneity with respect to $\epsilon_1$.

Consider a real number $x$, now this is a scalar because it is plain value. Its physical significance is the magnitude. If we club two such numbers $x$ and $y$ we get a vector$$\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\ y\end{array}\right)$$ Now if we club two such vectors we get a matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2 \\y_1 & y_2 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
The thing is from which space are you viewing the real number. If you are considering only the scalar space then $x$ is a scalar, if you are viewing from a vector space $x$ is a 1X1 vector if you are viewing from matrix space $x$ is a 1X1 matrix. So the hierarchy is like Scalar then Vector then Matrix. Any scalar can be represented as a matrix or a vector but not the other way round.

It is similar to the fact that is $2$ really a complex number. People say it is because in the complex domain it can be represented as $2+0i$,a complex number cant be represented as a real number because it is having real and imaginary parts.
Hope this helps...